# Yii2 save model

Tags: orm, yii2, yii2-basic-app

I want to update my entry:

```
$user_to = User::findByUsername($user_to_name);
```

It returns me an object, i update it like

```
$user_to->balance+=$model->money;
```

And save like:

```
$user_to->update();
```

or:

```
$user_to->save();
```

But i'm getting error:

> ```
>                 [0] => Username "das" has already been taken.
> ```

I don't know wat to do, because it's  update, not insert...

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in

```
return new static($user)
```

in findByUsername function.